# toggle between transactional and promotional sms in amazon sns

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-sns

**TL;DR** Wan't to specify *transactional/promotional* message type on the fly (as a param) without having to set the message attributes every time.

So I want to send OTPs to customer using amazon SNS and this is the code for the following:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sns')
response = client.publish(
               PhoneNumber='some_phone_number',
               Message='some_message'
           )
```

According to their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html), there are 2 message types:
 1. Transactional (Time critical delivery)
 2. Promotional (Non time critical delivery and cost effective)

I have an option to set the default message attributes using the `set_sms_attributes()` as follows:

```
client.set_sms_attributes(
           attributes={"DefaultSMSType": "Transactional" | "Promotional" }
)
```

I donot wan't to keep changing this param as they are defaults. I wan't to be able to specify the message type on the fly as a parameter in `publish()`

I checked out the `MessageAttributes` but according to their [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-attributes.html), it's not to specify the message type but contains metadata for the client to handle the message before processing it.

Is there a way to toggle the message type on the fly without having to set it in the default settings using the `set_sms_attributes` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set it using `'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType'` in the `publish()`. This attribute is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html), e.g.:

```
client = boto3.client('sns')
response = client.publish(
               PhoneNumber='some_phone_number',
               Message='some_message',
               MessageAttributes = {
                   'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {
                       'DataType': 'String',
                       'StringValue': 'Promotional'  # or 'Transactional'
                   }
               }
           )
```

Note: for some regions there is no cost difference between these 2 types.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: You just saved my coding career. Was stuck for the whole day on an issue

Answer (score 0):

You can pass attribute as Map

```
    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = new HashMap<String, 
    MessageAttributeValue>();
        
    smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType",new 
    MessageAttributeValue().withStringValue("Transactional").withDataType("String"));
```